# Double clicking Google Sheet Drawing with attached script opens Drawing editor - how to avoid?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using a Drawing as a way to call a script. My use case expects this button to be pressed in rapid succession sometimes (two or three times at once).

> I simply want the button to call the script multiple times (it does) without opening the edit drawing dialog.

- Are there permissions I can set to prevent the user from opening this dialog?
- Or is there a way to lock the drawing?
- Or is there a different way to create a button that can be used in this way? (I looked at onSelectionChange(e) but this doesn't solve my multiple click need.)

Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't right click + run script work? Please share sample copy of your sheet for us to work on. Thanks.

Comment: [Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15nSHmruvcIwKpQf-g5VAMf6TtDOQgtQ9s1NVf-c6vYo/edit?usp=sharing). The two buttons increment and decrement the counter, but double clicking on them opens the Drawing window.

Comment: What is the minimuminterval you expect between clicks?

Comment: It could be several in one second, perhaps 300ms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to not use a drawing at all. Here's how:

1. Make a nice snip of the UP arrow, and copy it to the clipboard
2. Select the cell where the arrow is now and delete the Drawing.
3. In the same cell paste the snip from the clipboard
4. Right click on the pasted Arrow image and assign the script to it.
5. Notice that you can click many times and it will work as you expect.
6. Repeat for the DOWN arrow.

Comment: This is fantastic, it works! Thank you so much!